# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent where clause on joining table from parent model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a fabrics table which links to one brand and one season. Running `App\fabrics::with('brand', 'season')->get()` gets me all the fabrics and their brand and season information which is fine (see below).

I want to get fabrics based on the season id. I tried:

`App\fabrics::with('brand', 'season')->where('season.id', '1')->get()`

but this doesn't work.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'season.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `fabrics` where `season`.`id` = 1)'
```

Is it possible to get fabrics and filter by one of its relationships?

Obviously I can get the fabrics from the season model App::season but I was wondering if it can be achieved from its parent (fabrics) model.

All the information from App\fabrics::with('brand', 'season')->get()

```
>>> App\fabrics::with('brand', 'season')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#794
     all: [
       App\Fabrics {#786
         id: 1,
         fabric_code: "GMAN01",
         fabric_design: "ANODA",
         fabric_price_group: "I",
         fabric_retail_price: "27.00",
         fabric_trade_price: null,
         fabric_width: 141,
         fabric_pattern_repeat: 1,
         fabric_fiber: "48% POLYESTER 44% COTTON 8% VISCOSE",
         fabric_online: 1,
         fabric_available: 1,
         fabric_meters_remaining: 256.78,
         fabric_virutal_meters_remaining: 216.28,
         created_at: "2016-12-02 10:52:09",
         updated_at: "2016-12-02 13:08:07",
         brand_id: 1,
         season_id: 1,
         brand: App\Brands {#742
           id: 1,
           brand_name: "*****",
           created_at: "2016-12-02 11:36:10",
           updated_at: "2016-12-02 11:36:10",
         },
         season: App\Seasons {#795
           id: 1,
           season_name: "Autumn/Winter 2016",
           season_code: "AW16",
           created_at: "2016-12-02 13:07:50",
           updated_at: "2016-12-02 13:07:50",
         },
       },
       App\Fabrics {#765
         id: 2,
         fabric_code: "GMAN02",
         fabric_design: "ANODA",
         fabric_price_group: "I",
         fabric_retail_price: "27.00",
         fabric_trade_price: null,
         fabric_width: 141,
         fabric_pattern_repeat: 1,
         fabric_fiber: "48% POLYESTER 44% COTTON 8% VISCOSE",
         fabric_online: 1,
         fabric_available: 0,
         fabric_meters_remaining: 20.0,
         fabric_virutal_meters_remaining: 17.0,
         created_at: "2016-12-02 10:52:09",
         updated_at: "2016-12-02 13:14:56",
         brand_id: 2,
         season_id: 1,
         brand: App\Brands {#770
           id: 2,
           brand_name: "*****",
           created_at: "2016-12-02 11:36:10",
           updated_at: "2016-12-02 11:36:10",
         },
         season: App\Seasons {#795},
       },
       App\Fabrics {#791
         id: 3,
         fabric_code: "JBBU01",
         fabric_design: "BURDOCK",
         fabric_price_group: "D",
         fabric_retail_price: "16.00",
         fabric_trade_price: null,
         fabric_width: 140,
         fabric_pattern_repeat: 64,
         fabric_fiber: "100% COTTON",
         fabric_online: 0,
         fabric_available: 1,
         fabric_meters_remaining: 856.1,
         fabric_virutal_meters_remaining: 856.1,
         created_at: "2016-12-02 10:52:09",
         updated_at: "2016-12-02 13:08:13",
         brand_id: 3,
         season_id: 4,
         brand: App\Brands {#787
           id: 3,
           brand_name: "*****",
           created_at: "2016-12-02 11:36:10",
           updated_at: "2016-12-02 11:36:10",
         },
         season: App\Seasons {#775
           id: 4,
           season_name: "Spring/Summer 2015",
           season_code: "SS15",
           created_at: "2016-12-02 13:07:50",
           updated_at: "2016-12-02 13:07:50",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the closure for [eager loads contraining](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
App\fabrics::with(['brand', 'season' => function($q) use($seasonId) {
    $q->where('id', $seasonId);
}])->get();
```

If you want to filter fabrics by season ID, use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
App\fabrics::with('brand', 'season')
    ->whereHas('season', function($q) use($seasonId) {
        $q->where('id', $seasonId);
    })->get();
```

Comment: +1 for the documentation link, I had no idea what the feature was called so that helps. Is it possible to pass multiple closures on the with()? for example filter by season id and filter by brand id?

Comment: Sure, you can use cloasure for every relation.

Comment: brilliant thank you. The $seasonId variable is created by Eloquent I'm guessing?

Comment: @twigg no, it's your variable. You can use an integer instead of it if you want (like in example in your question). In this case you don't need to add `use()` clause to the closure.

Comment: ah yes, with you. Okay thank you, I will accept once the time allows me

Comment: is it possible to have multiple whereHas clauses (closures) in the same query?

Comment: @twig sure. You can use multiple `whereHas()` and `orWhereHas()`.